# How to target every nth row starting from a specific row to change font colour and style?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to figure out how to target every 4th row starting from row 5 so that when there is text found the font colour is red and bold.

In the uploaded picture you'll see in row 5 I have Edit Access and 4 rows down I have it there again...I was hoping to make it so anytime there's an entry in the columns those would be red and emboldened.

Is this possible?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you want to format only the cells that have text? Or format the entire row if any cells have text?  Is there a reason you can't use **[conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f)**?

Comment: Hi there Ashleedawg, I'm looking to format the all the rows that say Edit Access that have to always be in bold red if new input is added or if existing input is there

Comment: Also I tried to do conditional formatting but I honestly didn't understand it much and wasn't sure what kind of formula would apply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear any existing Conditional Formatting, Select Row5 to as far down as required and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=MOD(ROW()-1,4)=0
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Comment: thank you Pnuts! this is really great, and I yeah I could have definitely worded it better lol

Answer (score 0):

Just use a conditional formatting rule. If you don't want to create one manually, here is the code to do so.

```
sub cfrEditAccess()
    with worksheets("sheet1")
        with .columns("B:AZ")
            .FormatConditions.Delete
            With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$A1=""Edit Access""")
                .font.Color = 255
                .font.Bold = True
            End With
        end with
    end with
end sub
```